# Создание массивов char из элементов массива

Tags: java, java-8

Всем доброго времени суток!
Имеется метод
*public static String QuestionsMarks(String str)*, который принимает в качестве параметра строку, которую вводит пользователь.
Строка такого типа: *fdshkjha5???6fjshh2???fhjshfs1????6fsfs*. Необходимо выяснить какую сумму образуют два числа между *???*. Одна из идей это: методом *split* разбить строку на массив подстрок и уже на основании элементов этого массива создать массивы *char*
Например, есть на входе строка: *jkhsd5???6sfsf*.

```
public class Questions_Marks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        QuestionsMarks(QuestionsMarks(s.nextLine()));
    }

    public static String QuestionsMarks(String str) {

        String [] parts = str.split("\\?\\?\\?");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
        for (int i = 0; i<parts.length;i++){

        }

        return str;
    }

}
```

Разбиваем ее на элементы массива *parts*. И получаем два элемента массива *jkhsd5* и *6sfsf*
Так вот вопрос:
Как создать массивы char из элементов массива parts? Т.е. char [] 1 = {*j,k,h,s,d,5*} и второй char [] 2 = {*6,s,f,s,f*}

Или я вообще в дебри ушёл и есть вариант намного легче для решения задачи.
Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что настоящая задача состоит не в получении массивов символов, а в том, чтобы суммировать именно целые числа, разделённые *ровно тремя* знаками вопроса.

Для решения такой задачи проще применить регулярное выражение, чтобы обнаружить пары чисел, подходящие под шаблон `"(\\d+)\\?{3}(\\d+)"`, и найти их сумму (сумму всех подходящих пар).

При этом удобнее воспользоваться *потоком совпадений*, который можно получить при помощи метода [`Matcher::results`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java9/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--), добавленного, впрочем, только в Java 9.

```java
String str = "fdshkjha5???6fjshh2???fhjshfs1????6fsfs";

int sum = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\?{3}(\\d+)").matcher(str)
    .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
    .mapToInt(mr -> Integer.parseInt(mr.group(1)) + Integer.parseInt(mr.group(2)))
    .sum();

System.out.println(sum); // 11
```

Если критично, чтобы код был совместим именно с Java 8, можно воспользоваться обычным циклом:

```java
String str = "fdshkjha5???6fjshh2???fhjshfs1????6fsfs";

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\?{3}(\\d+)").matcher(str);
int sum = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)) + Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
}
System.out.println(sum); // 11
```

---

Похожий вопрос, связанный с [вычислением суммы доходов в строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453248/).

Answer (score 0):

Разбейте строку на отдельные символы и поместите каждый из них в массив по порядку.
Далее по очереди проверяйте каждую ячейку массива. Если там число - помещайте его в специальную переменную, если нет - идите дальше по массиву. Когда получите два числа, суммируйте их.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А если таких чисел несколько? В отдельный массив?

Comment: @Alex_Lynx, именно так)

Comment: Спасибо большое)