# Коректно ли я написал код?

Tags: java, строки, инспекция-кода, числа

Есть задача, из строки извлеч числа, а потом их сложить.

```
public class Loader {


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";
    int spaceIndex = text.indexOf('5');
    int spaceIndex1 = text.indexOf('7');
    int spaceIndex2 = text.indexOf("30");
    
    String num1 = text.substring(15,19);
    String num2 = text.substring(35,39);
    String num3 = text.substring(56,61);
    
    int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(num1);
    int secondNum = Integer.parseInt(num2);
    int thirdNum = Integer.parseInt(num3);
    
    int sum = firstNum + thirdNum;
    System.out.println(sum);
    
    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println(num2);
    System.out.println(num3);
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Если в строку добавить 1 символ, ваш код сломается!

Comment: спасибо, даже не подумал об этом

Comment: 1) Вы не извлекаете произвольные целые числа из произвольной строки, а просто ищете некоторые числа, основываясь на _знании_, какие числа уже содержатся на каких позициях.  2) Вы даже не используете вычисленные индексы цифр `spaceIndex,spaceIndex1, spaceIndex2`.  3) При вычислении суммы вы "потеряли" второе слагаемое.

Answer (score 3):

Как по мне, это вообще не решение. Любое изменение исходной строки приводит к исключению, а какой смысл писать программу, которая может сложить только этих конкретных 3 числа только в этой конкретной строке? Сложите их на калькуляторе.

```
private final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String text = "Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей";
        
        List<Integer> allNumbers = findAllNumbers(text);
        
        int sum = allNumbers.stream().mapToInt(v->v).sum();
        System.out.println(sum);
        
        allNumbers.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Integer> findAllNumbers(String text) {                
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group()));
        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если стоит задача "извлечь" числа из строки, и сложить их, это можно сделать несколькими способами:

1. Разбить исходную строку по "нецифрам", используя `String::split`, при этом нужно отфильтровать возможные пустые строки:

```java
public static int sum(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+")) // Stream<String>  
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())    // убрать пустые строки
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  // IntStream
        .sum();
}

System.out.println(sum("Вася заработал 5000 рублей, Петя - 7563 рубля, а Маша - 30000 рублей"));
// -> 42563
```

Однако при этом способе будут складываться любые числа, даже если они перемешаны с буквами, т.е. "входят" в слова.  Также числа будут складываться без учёта размерностей.

2. Составить регулярное выражение для подбора нужных чисел (вероятно с указанием размерности, в данном случае рублей): `\b(\d+)\s+руб`

Затем следует использовать метод [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--), возвращающий поток совпадений `Stream<MatchResult>`.

```
public static int sum(String str) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d+)\\s+руб")
        .matcher(str)
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1)) // взять содержимое группы 1: \d+
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .sum();        
}
```